# Disable Airplane mode forever - 19.10

Tags: shortcut-keys, airplane-mode

I have a desktop computer that doesn't have a function key and I've never seen any setting for Airplane mode before.

I was doing a remote Zoom session with someone who was on a Mac and they hit some keyboard shortcut (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> I think?) which turned on Airplane Mode, thus disabling WiFi and disconnecting the Zoom session.

As a result, I was unable to use my keyboard or mouse and was forced to hard-reboot my computer since no other controls would respond to my input (I assume some kind of bug with Zoom not releasing screen control).

**How can I disable Airplane Mode from ever happening again on my desktop computer?**

Comment: Are you saying that somebody remote keyed something on their end and disabled *your* local wireless and input?

Comment: @user535733 Yes. That's exactly correct.

Comment: Does zoom allow control of remote machines like teamviewer? I'm not familiar with zoom.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity yes it's a similar function to Teamviewer - it was the first time I've used it, and the main difference seems to be that in Teamviewer each user has their own cursor, but in Zoom you have a shared cursor which I think is part of the problem I had, they had control but then WiFi disconnected leaving me without the ability to use the keyboard or mouse input.

Answer (score 0):

This command could help:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.rfkill active false
```

Just as warning though, it does disable your Bluetooth controls through the gui (but Bluetooth still works).

You should also not let people access your computer directly (through a meeting) because that brings a very big security flaw to your computer as anyone can basically control it.

Comment: I understand the risks with letting someone else have control. In this case, I was in the middle of a Codementor session and preventing them from having control kind of defeats the purpose of the service.